# Update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`) error coming up

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class NewComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      obj: [],
      externalObj: [],
    };
  }

getFunc = (external) => {
    ...
      arr = arr.filter(a => a.toLowerCase().includes('eg')
      this.setState({ obj: arr });
    
    return arr.map((Id) => {
      return <Legend key={Id} id={Id} title={Id}/>;
    });
  }

 render() { 
    return(
   this.getFunc(false);
)
}
}
```

This is the structure of my React component. I want to set obj in state to that arr **to use obj in some other method called completely differently**
I am getting this error - `Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

I kind of have an idea what is causing this error but I dont know what other thing I can do to achieve what I want - to be able to use this arr in some other method called seperately

Comment: Do it in `useEffect`.

Comment: How? how will I have this **arr** there?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting state inside your render function, so when it try to render it, it will set new state and render again, it might cause an infinite loop.

I'm not sure what this line do `this.setState({ obj: arr });`, but it should be moved somewhere into componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate or wherever you need it.

You can make your filter in one of those lifecycle methods and then render your array from state

**UPDATE**

In your class add componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount(){
  arr = arr.filter(a => a.toLowerCase().includes('eg')
      this.setState({ obj: arr });
}
```

Then in your getFunc

```
return this.state.obj && this.state.obj.map((Id) => {
      return <Legend key={Id} id={Id} title={Id}/>;
    });
```

Comment: If I move it there how can I access arr from there?

Comment: Just render your array from state

Comment: Sorry didnt understand~~I dont have arr in state thats y I want to store it in obj in state

Comment: In your case after setting state, you will have your arr in this.state.obj, so in your render you can do something like this `this.state.obj.map(...)`

Comment: setting state is not working that is what is giving the error - Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Comment: I'll update my answer with little example. You should move setState out of your render.